# split text data to train and test according to its word distribution

Tags: machine-learning, python

I have a list of sentences as a dataset for a classification task and a dictionary object that contains the frequency of each word in the dataset. I want to split the data into two lists of train set and test set such that the distribution of words frequency in both lists be the same.
How can I do this in python?